# Store GitLab server credentials in GitKraken

Tags: git, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, gitkraken

Using GitKraken 2.0.1 (latest version in time of writing), the software asks me regularly about the account credentials of my GitLab account when I want to push or pull. Recently, I switched my development machine from Windows 10 to Kubuntu. Before that, I used SourceTree. There it was possible to store the login-data permanent.

I couldn't find any similar way in GitKraken. Also, there is no kind of *remember me* checkbox:

[image]

The connection to GitLab is made using HTTP over a VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649014/6309), GitKraken would use the `git config credential.helper`.

Make sure to set one, preferably the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (which is cross-platform), and to enter your credentials (username/token) at the next prompt: said credentials will be cached in the credential manager and automatically reused on subsequent pushes.