# Gitkraken says repo is private but its public

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I have my repo stored on GitHub and visibility is public but since a few days when I try to open the repository on Gitgraken, it says that the repo I'm trying to open is private and it won't let me access it.

Things I have tried:

- I tried closing and opening Gitkraken.
- Uninstalled Gitkraken, removed the directory in AppData and reinstalled Gitkraken.
- Make sure that the repo is indeed public.
- I also tried opening the repo again by browsing to the directory rather than trying to open it from the recent projects.

However, it still displays that message.
I have tons of projects and that's the only project which gets this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if:

- GitKraken is using an HTTPS URL to access that repository
- if `git config credential.helper` is set

If other projects (under the same GitHub user account) are accessible from GitKraken, then it is not an authentication issue.
What remains could be a typo in the repository name.

Do check the [GitKraken logs](https://support.gitkraken.com/known-issues/error-logs/) to see if there is any more clue.

Comment: I have a repo that it just started doing this with, possibly after the 8.0 update? It works with SSH but not HTTPS. https://github.com/DiscordPP/plugin-endpoints

Oh and `git config credential.helper` is set as `manager-core`

Comment: @Aido What password is cached in the credential manager? It needs now to be a PAT (Personal Access Token)

Comment: I'll check on that. The weird thing is that it's only that specific repo. Not even other repos from the org have the same issue.

Comment: It won't let me disconnect GitHub because I signed in with it and I reinstalled GitKraken but that didn't wipe any config stuff

Oh but it fixed it lol

Comment: @Aido OK. It seems you have managed to solve this issue, well done.

Comment: I disconnected and reconnected GitKraken from my GitHub account, and that seemed to resolve the problem for me.

Comment: @AmitaiB Great! That seems a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me, unsetting the local configs `remote.personal_origin.url` and `remote.personal_origin.fetch` solved the issues.

Commands:

```
git config --local --unset remote.personal_origin.url
git config --local --unset remote.personal_origin.fetch
```